# How to reference a child of a child

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am currently using Firebase and Dialogflow. I wish to take in 2 parameters,courses and facilities Location, and access the information of the child of a child, however I am not sure how to do so. I will attach an image of the database for reference.

Firebase Database:

[image: Firebase Database reference]

```
    else if (action === 'course_day') {                                    //For courses 
    const product = request.body.queryResult.parameters.courses.trim();
    const product = request.body.queryResult.parameters.facilitiesLocation.trim();
    const ref = db.ref(`courseday/${product.toLowerCase()}`);

    ref.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
        const result = snapshot.val();
        if (result === null) {
            response.json({
                fulfillmentText: `We do not have such a course.Simply say, for example, 'What day is Chinese Calligraphy on?'!`
            });
            return;
        }
        response.json({
            fulfillmentText: `${product} lessons are on ${result.day}`,
            source: action
        });

    }).catch((err) => {
        response.json({
            fulfillmentText: `I don't know what is it`
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

On calling the 'once' function in the 'datasnapshot' you will receive the whole underlying data as a JSON. So all you have to do is move into this JSON and get the required value.

In this case, let's say your ref is pointing to 'test' branch of your db then when you call ref.once you will receive everything under that branch.

Hope this helps

Comment: My problem is that I have to take in two parameters from the user, for example, Aikido for course, and test for facilitiesLocation. However the user could also request for Aikido as the course and testing as the facilitiesLocation. Is there any way to go around doing this?

Comment: If that's the case, the variable data being as a child for the constant data will help.

Comment: You must put test and testing inside aikido

Comment: I see where you are coming from, but how would I call it? 
As you can see in my code,
        fulfillmentText: `${product} lessons are on ${result.day}`,
where ${result.day} calls for the day of the course. However, for example, both 'test' and 'testing' are the course locations. Any way to call either of them based on the user's input?